# V8/WebAssembly version supported in node 7.4.0?

Tags: node.js, webassembly

I see the following error in the `WebAssembly.compile` function when I try to compile binary WebAssembly in node 7.4.0 on OS X:

> Result = expected version 0b 00 00 00, found 0d 00 00 00

So the V8 engine seems not to handle the binary format defined [here](http://webassembly.org/docs/binary-encoding/).

When is it supposed to happen?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow new user! It would be helpful for us if you could provide the related code sample which is causing this error. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The WebAssembly specification has not been finalized yet. The current testing version is 0xd (which is produced by emscripten and other wasm tools), but once the spec is finalized we will reset the version to 1. We expect this to happen reasonably soon, but I couldn't say how long it will take for that to end up in a node.js build.

Answer (score 1):

Version 1 (also called MVP or Minimum Viable Product) of the WebAssembly specification is the one that is currently supported by most browsers. Support for version 1 has landed in the version 8 of node (https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/).

Answer (score 0):

Node.js webassembly feature depends on V8 and the version that support webassembly is V8 5.7.492, for that reason you need to wait until Node.js updates its version of V8.

Currently Node.js is using 5.5 (you can see that here https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V7.md#7.7.2)

So in the meantime, I recommend you use firefox or chrome.